# getString() from ID throws Resources$NotFoundException exception

Tags: android, android-resources

I'm trying to send String id from one method to another but when I try getString() to get the value I get an Resources$NotFoundException exception.

Method to get String:

```
    private static int getDefaultPropertyStringId(SettingsPropertyType settingsPropertyType, Context context) {

    int stringId;

    switch (settingsPropertyType) {
        case START_UP_SCREEN:
            stringId = R.string.settings_start_screen_map;
            break;
        case MAP:
            stringId = R.string.settings_map_normal;
            break;
        case REFRESH_TIME:
            stringId = R.string.settings_refresh_time_every_minute;
            break;
        case DISTANCE_UNIT:
            stringId = R.string.settings_distance_units_meters;
            break;
        default:
            stringId = R.string.default_settings;
            break;
    }
    return stringId;
}
```

If I make a get String with the return I can get the value from Strings resources:
[image]

This method is called when I try to get a value from preferences but it does not exist. The value I get is the default one. But if I try to get the default value in the method where getDefaultPropertyStringId() is called I get the error:

[image]

The id is the same inside getDefaultPropertyStringId() return and inside the calling method but when I try to get the string the error appears.

Does somebody know why is that happening?

A part from that, does anyone knows where I can relate the id to the string? Any file that I can relate them or something.

Thank you

Comment: try context.getResources().getString(id);

Comment: Adding context.getResources().getString(id) throws the same error

Comment: Post the code how you are calling `getDefaultPropertyStringId` method

Comment: Varad, the code where I call getDefaultPropertyStringId is inside the second image

Answer (score 1):

In android Studio, From File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart

Get String like this

```
 stringId = getResources().getString(R.string.settings_start_screen_map);
```

Comment: Invalidates Caches gives me the same error. As for change the code to return a string instead of the id, I want first to know why I can not get the string out of the method with the same id.

Comment: what you want string or id?

Comment: get the id to use it after

Comment: For id you have to get like this  R.string.settings_start_screen_map

Answer (score 0):

The error was that the string id I was getting from Shared was from a deleted String inside strings.xml making the application crash.